# Where is localhost folder

Tags: iis

I am trying to find physical path of localhost.

Is it possible to find physical path of localhost when I running my web sit on IIS or Visual Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Look in the site properties in IIS Manager.

Answer (score 5):

I think by default the path to IIS localhost is

C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1425800/649427) to be helpful. Not if you're using IIS, of course, but I'm not, and I still landed on this question.

Basically, figure out where you installed Apache, like maybe C:\Program Files\Apache24, and look for httpd.conf

Within that file, look for DocumentRoot. That stores the path to your localhost directory.

Answer (score -2):

It usually is htdocs on Windows systems